# VBA Excel setfocus on Dropdown box

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu, setfocus

I am trying to set the focus in Excel through VBA code towards a dropdown box. I have tried various things which bring unwanted results. The item below is the only one I have got to focus on the drop down box but it is selecting the dropdown as if it was selected under developer (with the resizing dots), whereas I just want it to point to the cell if thats possible. I don't want the user to be able to resize the dropdown or anything and its locked so its weird that it would do that.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("DropDown1").Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub TestFocus()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim dd As DropDown

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set dd = ws.Shapes("DropDown1").OLEFormat.Object

    dd.TopLeftCell.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems to only select the upper left cell. I dont think its actually possible to put focus inside the dropdown box.. Thanks

Comment: Actually it is possible.  See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but since no one actually answered the Op's question I felt I should post this.  There is a hidden `.Activate` method for OLE objects which does not appear in Intellisense as you type.

This code activates the combo-box, assuming the combo-box is on the active worksheet.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oleObj As OLEObject
    Set oleObj = Excel.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Item("TempCombo")

    oleObj.Activate
End Sub
```